# Proof the discontinuity of function with $\epsilon-\delta$ for continuous function

Tags: solution-verification, continuity

I want to prove, that function is discontinuous with $\epsilon-\delta$, but my function is continuous $f(x):= x$. So definiton of discontinuity:

$f$ is discontinuous at $c$ $\iff$ $\exists \epsilon>0,$ such that $\forall \delta>0 \ \exists x$ such that $|x-c|<\delta \land |f(x)-f(c)| \geq \epsilon$. Because my function is continuous I want to get a contradiction somewhere in my proof, but I didn't get it or I understand something wrong. So I want to prove discontinuity at point $0$.

$\textbf{Proof:}$ Given $\delta>0$, then $|x-0|=|x|< \delta$. Now I have to find some $x$, such that $|f(x)-f(0)|=|x-0|=|x| \geq \epsilon$. So I will take $x:=2\epsilon$, then $|f(x)-f(0)|=|x-0|=|x|=|2\epsilon| \geq \epsilon$ its true for any $\epsilon>0$. But we know, that its absurd=)

Can somebody help me? Where do I missunderstand ? Thank you!

Comment: So you're trying to prove $f(x) = x$ is continuous by supposing it is discontinuous and then trying to get a contradiction. That's a possible approach although it's a bit unusual. Why not just directly prove that it is continuous, using the definition of continuous?

Comment: The problem lies in the quantifications. In particular, you cannot choose $x$ and $\varepsilon$ freely like that, and especially you cannot just choose $x=2\varepsilon$. Go back to the definition and make sure you get its negation right

Comment: @AdamRubinson no) I want to prove, that function is discontinuous, $\textbf{but}$, for function that is continuous. It will help me to feel this topic better

Comment: @Lorago I think I understand it.  Negation of continuity at point $c$ is $\exists \epsilon>0$ such that $\forall \delta>0, \ \exists x$  with $|x-c|<\delta$ and $|f(x)-f(x)| \geq \epsilon$. So I can choose $\epsilon$, for which it works, but $x$ has to be less than $\delta$ and it may be not hold for my $x:=2\epsilon$. Am I right?

Comment: But you cannot prove that a continuous function is discontinuous. You realise this, right? A real function is either continuous or discontinuous. It cannot be both. In fact, the very definition of *discontinuous* is: "not continuous."

Comment: @AdamRubinson I understand it. But what will be, if I try to prove, that function is discontinuous, if function is continuous? I will get contradiction or something will be wrong.

Comment: Yes, you should get a contradiction of some kind. But I said that in my first comment: "So you're trying to prove $f(x)=x$ is continuous by supposing it is discontinuous and then trying to get a contradiction." and you said "no". So did you mean "yes" instead of "no"? If not, that I'm not sure I understand what you're getting at.

Comment: @AdamRubinson I am so sorry, I meaned "yes", you are right)